# How to get days (monday ,tuesday.....) between two different dates?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to show a report, which will show weekly report for training session.. from Monday to Saturday some time Sunday with the number of participants per day.
i want sql query to complete this task.
eg.

```
code    days   mon  tues Wed thurs fri sat sun
10001   3      22   22  22   0     0   0   0
10002   5      10   10  10   10    10  0   0  and so on....
```

Here no. of participants are same for all days of that training session.

**Updated Query**

.....................my query as per @competent_tech suggestion .........................

```
CREATE VIEW SessionDOW
AS
SELECT tcapp_id,title,
case when programtype=1 then 'YP' else 'SP' end programtype,
case when NonResidential=2 then 'Res' else 'Non Res.' end nonresidential,duration, 
fromdate,TODATE,
Training_Calendar.Participents, 
         StartDOW = DATEPART(weekday, FromDate) ,
         EndDOW = DATEPART(weekday, FromDate)+Duration -1,

           weekenddate=DATEPART(d,CONVERT(date,'12-12-2011'))+6
    FROM Training_Calendar

GO

select * from sessiondow

CREATE VIEW SessionDays
AS
  SELECT SessionDOW.*,
         MON = CASE WHEN (2 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW)  OR (EndDow >= 2 + 7) THEN Participents ELSE 0 END ,
         TUE = CASE WHEN (3 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 3 + 7) THEN Participents ELSE 0 END ,
         WED = CASE WHEN (4 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 4 + 7) THEN Participents ELSE 0 END ,
         THURS = CASE WHEN (5 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 5 + 7) THEN Participents ELSE 0 END ,
         FRI = CASE WHEN (6 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 6 + 7) THEN Participents ELSE 0 END ,
         SAT = CASE WHEN (7 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 0 + 7) THEN Participents ELSE 0 END,
           SUN = CASE WHEN (1 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 1 + 7) THEN Participents  ELSE 0 END 
    FROM SessionDOW
GO


SELECT e.* 
FROM SessionDays e INNER JOIN Training_Calendar a ON e.tcapp_id = a.TCApp_Id
GROUP BY e.TCApp_Id,e.title,
e.programtype,
e.nonresidential,e.duration, 
e.Participents, 
e.StartDOW ,
e.EndDOW,sun,MON,tue,wed,thurs,fri,SAT,e.FromDate,e.todate,e.weekenddate
```

which give me following result

```
tcapp_id    title   programtype nonresidential  duration    fromdate    TODATE  Participents    StartDOW    EndDOW  weekenddate MON TUE WED THURS   FRI SAT SUN
2011-12/CHD-10001   testing SP  Res 10  2011-12-05  2011-12-14  60  2   11  18  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
2011-12/CIT-10001   Training of Palak Technical Officer YP  Res 2   2011-12-13  2011-12-14  45  3   4   18  0   45  45  0   0   0   0
2011-12/SIRD-10001  Induction Level Training Programme for JE's of MESCT    YP  Res 4   2011-12-12  2011-12-15  25  2   5   18  25  25  25  25  0   0   0
2011-12/SIUD-10001  Extempore Leadership Skills Workshop    SP  Non Res.    5   2011-12-14  2011-12-18  35  4   8   18  0   0   35  35  35  35  35
2011-12/SIUD-10002  fdgd    YP  Res 6   2011-12-15  2011-12-20  80  5   10  18  80  80  0   80  80  80  80
```

here week start from 12th dec and end to 18th dec but training session start from 5th dec and ends at 14th dec but still next few days(15,16,17,18) showing participants value. please help.

Comment: It completely depends on the structure of your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an SQL Server database, then your query would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT CODE ,
       SUM(1) AS DAYS ,
       SUN = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
       MON = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
       TUE = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
       WED = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
       THURS = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
       FRI = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
       SAT = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, TimeStamp) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM Event
GROUP BY code
```

Where `Timestamp` is the name of the column containing the date of the training and `Event` is the name of the table.

**Update**

The above query assumes that one record exists in the database for each student for each day they attend a class.

However, if the database design is such that there is one record for the session that specifies a start date and a number of days and another table where attendees are registered for a given session, then the query becomes a bit different.

Assuming the following rough table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Sessions
(
   code INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
   date DATETIME NOT NULL ,
   DAYS INT NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (code)
)
CREATE TABLE Attendees
(
   id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
   code INT NOT NULL ,
   NAME NVARCHAR(100)
   PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
   FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES sessions (code)
)
```

We first create a view to calculate the start and end day of week (this makes ensuing views easier to understand):

```
CREATE VIEW SessionDOW
AS
  SELECT CODE ,
         DAYS ,
         StartDOW = DATEPART(weekday, date) ,
         EndDOW = DATEPART(weekday, date) + DAYS 
    FROM Sessions
GO
```

We then create a view to record 1 for each day of the week that the session is running. Note that this view takes into account a session that spans two weeks:

```
CREATE VIEW SessionDays
AS
  SELECT CODE ,
         DAYS ,
         SUN = CASE WHEN (0 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 0 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
         MON = CASE WHEN (1 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 1 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
         TUE = CASE WHEN (2 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 2 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
         WED = CASE WHEN (3 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 3 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
         THURS = CASE WHEN (4 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 4 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
         FRI = CASE WHEN (5 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 5 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
         SAT = CASE WHEN (6 BETWEEN StartDOW AND EndDOW) OR (EndDow >= 6 + 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM SessionDOW
GO
```

Finally, we join the sessiondays count with the students attending each session and add up the values:

```
  SELECT e.CODE ,
         MAX(DAYS) AS DAYS ,
         SUN = SUM(SUN) ,
         MON = SUM(MON) ,
         TUE = SUM(TUE) ,
         WED = SUM(WED) ,
         THURS = SUM(THURS) ,
         FRI = SUM(FRI) ,
         SAT = SUM(SAT)
    FROM SessionDays e INNER JOIN Attendees a ON e.code = a.code
GROUP BY e.code
```

Comment: thanks competent_tech. but i want to display no. of participants according to days.. if training session is for 3 days starting from Monday to Wednesday then in report, for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday participants no. should be 25 or whatever for that training session. Here can i pass multiple dates instead of single date?

Comment: @Mayur_Vartak: How the query is structured is going to depend completely on your database. The query in my answer is designed assuming that each student's presence is recorded separately for each day of the session, which could be important depending on how your needs. For example, if 2 students missed the last day, is this important? Or do you just need to know how many registered or were there on the first day?

Comment: @Mayur_Vartak: I have updated the answer to show an alternate solution.

Comment: thanks i update my query. please check and find solution for me.